# How to apply effect just to background image and not text

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-transitions

I'm searching a way to make an css effect but with exception of not applying the effect to the letters and the buttons (Only to the image), so I need create a rule in css. I can't change the order of the things.
With my code, I get something like this.

### [image: My current code works so]

This is my code, like you can see I applied some effect in css and this is getting applied to all. I only need it for the image.

```css
.myimage01 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.myimage01:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<li id="armonioso-text-2" class="widget widget_armonioso_text">
  <div class="armonioso-textwidget-wrapper  armonioso-textwidget-no-paddings">
    
    <!-- Here I'm currently Applying the efect -->
    <div class="armonioso-textwidget myimage01" data-style="background-image: url(http:www.myurl.com/image.jpg);padding: 40px 30px ;color: #ffffff;text-align: center;">
      <h5>hello world</h5>
      <h3>Here how works</h3>
      <p>Take a look of new things
        <p><a class="btn alt" href="about/index.html" target="_self">About me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Here I'm currently Applying the efect -->
</li>
```

When I apply the effect apply the effect to the letters (`h5`, `h3`, `p` and the `button` with `btn` class)

I don't want the effect for them, only for the `background-image`.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for transition backgrounds use the property `background-size`, and use `background-position` to adjust as fits you better

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.myimage01 {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position:center center;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/900);
  padding: 40px 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
.myimage01:hover {
  background-size: 130%;
}
```

```html
<li id="armonioso-text-2" class="widget widget_armonioso_text">
  <div class="armonioso-textwidget-wrapper  armonioso-textwidget-no-paddings">
    <!-- Here I'm currently Applying the efect -->
    <div class="armonioso-textwidget myimage01">
      <h5>hello world</h5>
      <h3>Here how works</h3>
      <p>Take a look of new things
        <p><a class="btn alt" href="about/index.html" target="_self">About me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Here I'm currently Applying the efect -->
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use background-size for transition:

```css
div { 
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/);
  background-size: 100%; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:50% 50%;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  transition: background-size 200ms linear;

  text-align:center;
  line-height:200px;

 }

div:hover {
  background-size: 120%; 
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some text 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to transform the `background-size` property instead of scaling the whole container.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply transform on `background-size`, `background-position` to get the effect on the background image.

```css
.myimage01 {
  background-size:100%;
  background-position:0px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: all;
  transform: all;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.myimage01:hover {
  background-size:140%;
  background-position:-50px -50px;
  -webkit-transform: all;
  transform: all;
}
```

```html
<li id="armonioso-text-2" class="widget widget_armonioso_text">
  <div class="armonioso-textwidget-wrapper  armonioso-textwidget-no-paddings">
    
    <!-- Here I'm currently Applying the efect -->
    <div class="armonioso-textwidget myimage01" style="background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/600x200/000/fff);padding: 40px 30px ;color: #ffffff;text-align: center;">
      <h5>hello world</h5>
      <h3>Here how works</h3>
      <p>Take a look of new things
        <p><a class="btn alt" href="about/index.html" target="_self">About me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Here I'm currently Applying the efect -->
</li>
```